# String и StringBuilder

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder alphabet = new StringBuilder("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя ");
    String text= "привет меня зовут антон я программист Java";
    StringBuilder textResult = new StringBuilder(text);
    for(int i =0; i< text.length(); i++)
    {

        textResult.insert(i, alphabet.indexOf(____text[i]____ // Здесь выдает ошибку Array type expected; found java.lang.String));

    }
       System.out.print(textResult);
   }
}
```

В коде я расписал где эта ошибка и что пишет. Суть программы - менять буквы в тексте на их порядковый номер в алфавите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringBuilder` тут не имеет смысла использовать, используйте обычную строку. Также можете использовать метод `substring`, чтобы получить i-й символ строки `text`:

```
String alphabet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя ";
String text= "привет меня зовут антон я программист Java";
StringBuilder textResult = new StringBuilder(text);
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    textResult.insert(i, alphabet.indexOf(text.substring(i, i+1)));
}
System.out.println(textResult);
```

Тест на [ideone](http://ideone.com/R8v8Iz).

Answer (score 1):

у тебя text типа String - это не массив!!!
 можно сделать примерно так:

```
  public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
StringBuilder alphabet = new StringBuilder("abcdef");
String text= "abc def adddd ef";
String text1 = text.replaceAll(" ", "");
char[] ch = text1.toCharArray();
StringBuilder textResult = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
{

  textResult.append(alphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(ch[i])) + 1);

}
 System.out.print(textResult);
} 
}
```

Comment: У массива нет метода length(), только свойство и у билдера нет метода `indexOf` для `indexOf(char)`